# places api Unable to get property 'address_components' of undefined or null reference

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

working with the google places api and cannot figure why autocomplete is returning undefined here on call to get places.
what developer tools shows is. 
address_components is what should be returned on a call to autocomplete.getPlace
Unable to get property 'address_components' of undefined or null reference

```
function initAutoCompleteDynamic() {
var slideID = 99;
var idx = 99 - slideID;
var propcount = 5;

  for (var i = 0; i < propcount; i++) {
    var propaddress = "prop1address" + i;
    var autocomplete = autocomplete + i;
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        document.getElementById(propaddress)),
        { types: ['geocode'] };
       autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillinAddressDynamic);


  }
}
```

and in fillinAddressDynamic

```
     var place=autocomplete.getPlace():
      for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    alert("i am in the loop");
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    var field = addressType;
    var completeaddress1 = '';
    var propaddress = 'prop1address' + i;
    var strnum = 'streetnumber' + i;
    CR(i);//calling component resolver. 


    if (componentFormProduction[addressType]) {
        var val = place.address_components[i][componentFormProduction[addressType]];
        document.getElementById(CR[addressType]).value = val;

        if (field == "street_number") {
            var streetnum = document.getElementById(strnum).value = val;

        }
        if (field == "route") {
            if (streetnum) {
                completeaddress1 = streetnum + ' ' + val;
            }
            else {
                completeaddress1 = val;
            }
            document.getElementById('prop1address0').value = completeaddress1;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This would happen if the user (or you) hits Enter without clicking on a suggestion.

Typically the sequence of event is like this:

1. user enters input
2. JavaScript queries Autocomplete for suggestions
3. user clicks on a suggestion
4. JavaScript queries Details, replaces user input with Details responses' fields (incl. `address_components`) **and** fires the `places_changed` event
5. handler for `places_changed` will obtain the Place object from Details response by calling `getPlace()`

However, it may also be like this:

1. user enters input
2. JavaScript queries Autocomplete for suggestions
3. user disregards suggestions and hits `Enter` without clicking on one
4. JavaScript fires the `places_changed` event without querying Details or modifying user input
5. handler for `places_changed` calls `getPlace()` and gets a nearly empty Place object, with only the `name` field containing the raw user input.

It is for you to decide what to do with raw user input, here are some examples:

This tool uses the JavaScript Geocoding service to search for that input:
https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/

This example (address form) does nothing with it:
https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

This (very basic) example will show an error message reporting no details:
https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/places-autocomplete

Comment: No its not due to not selecting an address, i believe it is due to the async nature of the call, this is dynamically loaded data coming from google api, I think the fix would be to use a custom deferred object, it seems to be a timing error sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't deferred should fix it/make it wait long enough to complete.